# Form Validation Semantic UI, Error message not working when define inline = false

Tags: validation

```
inline : true,
on     : 'blur',
```

when I define inline = 'true' ,
Error message is working just fine, like 'picture1/3'

but... when i define inline = 'false', error message in quote 'not blank' is missing, like 'picture2/3'

```
inline : false,
on     : 'blur',
```

Until I press submit, error message in quote 'not blank' is appear
, like 'picture3/3'

[image: Picture 1/3,2/3,3/3]

Comment: It is almost impossible to make sense of your question without knowing what technologies / libraries / frameworks you are using. Please edit your question and add the relevant information (including tags). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, what result you want to achieve.
If you don't want an inline message, just remove 'inline' setting altogether, as it is 'false' by default.
If you don't want  a ui message error block appearing below your form - remove

```
<div class="ui error message"></div>
```

from your html.